# CXF WADL2Java does not produce the right input parameters

Tags: java, cxf, wadl

I went through the documentation, which helped me figure out several issues I had, but not the following two problems:

1) I have got a get(GET) method: `get(@Context Request request, @PathParam("isbn")String isbn)`
How do I formulate the WADL for it so that I get the @Context in the produced Java code?

2) I have got a update (PUT) method: `update(@PathParam("isbn") String isbn, BookState st)`
How do I formuate the WADL to get the BookState in the produced Java code?

Here is my current WADL, which does not do it:

```
<resource path="/{isbn}">

        .... 
        <method name="GET" id="get" >
                <request />
                <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="prefix1:book" />
                </response>
        </method>
        <method name="PUT" id="update" >
                <request>
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="prefix1:book" />

                </request>
                <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream" />
                </response>
        </method>
</resource>
```

Comment: No answers yet. Back to Google. I'll come back and answer once I figure it out.